# Timeouts accessing Google Spreadsheet inside Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets-api

we encounter some problems when inserting multiple columns to Google
spreadsheets from Google App Engine. We inserting from a spreadsheet
containing 600 lines with 10 columns each. It is an append only
insertion. We starting to have timeouts when inserting the cells one
or two weeks again.

We are using the following call to insert *one* cell in java:

```
CellEntry cellEntry = new CellEntry(row, column, "the value of the cell");
serviceWrapper.insert(worksheet.getCellFeedUrl(), cellEntry);
```

Can we make batch request for new cell (didn't see it in the library),
how can we get rid of these timeouts (two seconds), or did the
spreadsheet could not work at this rates (did we need to make pause
between each or batch of requests?)

Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create a batch request for a `new cell`. [Google Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data) supports updating an entrie column, row other set of cells in a single request. This is offered to improve performance over making large sets of individual requests. This process is called "batching requests".

A number of batch operations can be combined into a single request. The two types of batch operations supported are query and update. `insert and delete are not supported` because the cells feed cannot be used to insert or delete cells. Remember that the worksheets feed must be used to do that.

`query and update` can be combined in any size set, and sent to the API in a single request. The API responds with information on the status of each individual operation within the batch. For query requests, the result is the requested cell. For update requests, the result includes the manipulated cell with new values.

Note: Version v4 of the Google Sheets API is now available! This [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration) shows how to update applications to use v4.

Found this blog, shows how to add multiple columns to Google Spreadsheets: http://trevorfox.com/2015/11/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-google-spreadsheets